# PHP: Validate a given string is a valid number

Tags: php, preg-match

I am trying to write a function that validates whether or not a given string is a valid number. I know I can use PHP is_numeric(), but the requirements is that the function needs to recognize commas as valid when:

- Commas are in the whole number part of the number
- Each comma has 3 whole number digits following it
- At least one digit left of each comma
- No more than 3 contiguous digits to the left of a comma

For instance:
It should recognize: 1,000,230 not ,021,201 or 1,023,12
It should also recognize positive and negative and dollar sign in front of it.

I am thinking to use preg_match to check the number format but I am not familiar with preg_match. Can you help me with this ? Any tip is appreciated ! Thank you !

Comment: Are you validating an int of a floating point number?

Comment: Yes including floating point. I want to check the format first. If the format is matched, I can use is_numeric() to validate.

Comment: The `Intl` library's `NumberFormat`, specifically [`NumberFormat::parseCurrency()`](http://php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parsecurrency.php), is an interesting alternative. However, it appears that the currency symbol must be present - your question seems to suggest that a currency symbol might be optional in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this function:

```
function hasNumericFormat($str) {
    return preg_match("/^[-+]?[$]?([1-9]\d{0,2}(,\d{3})*|0)(\.\d+)?$/", $str);
}
```

Test code:

```
function test($str) {
    if (hasNumericFormat($str)) {
        echo "$str is OK<br>";
    } else {
        echo "$str violates numerical format<br>";
    }
}

test("-$1,234,567.89"); // ok
test(",123,567.89"); // not ok: digit missing before comma
test("1,123,56"); // not ok: not 3 digits in last group
test("-0,123,567"); // not ok: first digit is zero
test("+0"); // ok
```

See it run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/599295)

Comment: Thank you trincot ! I think this is what I need ! Have a great holiday wkend !

Comment: Sorry but what if the given string contains no comma at all, can I use the expression like this "/^[-+]?[$]?([1-9]\d*)(\.\d+)?$/" ?

Answer (score 2):

No regex needed. Strip commas, then reformat with number_format. If that matches your original input, you're good.

```
if (number_format(str_replace(',', '', $number)) === $number) {
   // pass
}
```

You can adjust how you want to handle decimals by providing a second argument to number_format().

Comment: Thanks Alex. But the I didn't want to strip commas because of the requirements. If the user inputs 1,000,12,012 . It should return false because there should be 3 digits following after the comma.

Comment: The code works as you recommend -- the stripping is only done temporarily so that the value passed to number_format() is a valid integer. The contents of the variable is not changed.

Comment: That said, in general, you don't want to store formatted numbers. Your storage should contain the base value in its native form, and visual formatting like commas and dollar signs should happen at the time the number is displayed.

Answer (score 1):

The Intl library's NumberFormatter may be sufficient for you.

[The NumberFormatter class](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.numberformatter.php#class.numberformatter)

[NumberFormatter::parse](https://www.php.net/manual/en/numberformatter.parse.php)

**NOTE:** You may need to install or enable the *Int* library extension to use `NumberFormatter` class.

- To enable the extension, check your php.ini file(`C:\xampp\php\php.ini`) and search for `extension=intl`. Remove the prepended `;` if it exists. Restart Apache server and give it a try.

This extension is [bundled with PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intl.requirements.php) as of PHP version 5.3.0.

```
/**
 * Parse a number.
 *
 * @param string $locale - The locale of the formatted number.
 * @param string $number - Formatted number.
 * @return mixed - The value of the parsed number or FALSE on error.
 */
function parse_number(string $number, $locale)
{
    return (new NumberFormatter($locale, NumberFormatter::DECIMAL))
        ->parse(trim($number));
}

echo parse_number('4.678.567.345,3827', 'de_DE'); // 4678567345.3827
echo parse_number('4.678567.345,3827', 'de_DE'); // FALSE

echo parse_number('4,678,567,345.3827', 'en_US'); // 4678567345.3827
echo parse_number(',678567,345.3827', 'en_US'); // FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

I will write it like this:

```
if (preg_match('~\A(?>[1-9][0-9]{0,2}(?:,[0-9]{3})*|0)(?:\.[0-9]+)?\z~', $number)) {
    // true
} else {
    // false
}
```

details:

```
~ # my favourite pattern delimiter
\A # start of the string
(?>  # group for integer part:
     # I made it atomic to fail faster when there aren't exactly 3 digits
     # between commas
    [1-9] [0-9]{0,2} # beginning doesn't start with a zero
    (?:,[0-9]{3})*   # zero or more 3 digits groups
  |                  # OR
    0                # zero alone
)
(?:  # optional group for decimals
    \.[0-9]+ # at least 1 digit
)?
\z # end of the string
~
```

Note that I have chosen to not allow numbers with a leading zero like `012`, numbers without an integer part like `.12` or integers with a dot like `12.` but feel free to edit the pattern if it isn't what you want.

Comment: Thank you for your help and explanation !